# How do I stop Jetty

Tags: jetty

I am new to Jetty and client/server architectures.

I managed to write a jetty server in eclipse and it works.

But how I can stop a jetty server? I heard something about stop.jar and start.jar. Where I can find it? Is it integrated in jetty-all-jar?

Answer (score 24):

The various `jetty-all.jar` artifacts can be used for embedded jetty usage.  If you decide to use this jar, you have to manage your own startup / shutdown.

***Update: 2015*** : As of Jetty 9, the use of `jetty-all.jar` as a dependency is deprecated.  This is because as of Jetty 9, it is now impossible to satisfy "all" of Jetty in a single aggregate jar.  There are components of Jetty that cannot be included as they will cause problems with this aggregate jar.  The future of Jetty, with HTTP/2 support, also makes this aggregate jar less useful as a dependency.

**Typical Embedded Mode usage**

The thread that starts the server:

```
Server server = new Server();
// various server configuration lines
// ...

// Start server (on current thread)
server.start();

// Have current thread wait till server is done running
server.join();
```

The other thread that tells the server to shutdown

```
// Have server stop running
server.stop();
```

At this point the original thread's wait on `server.join();` is complete and that thread continues to run.

**Standard Distribution Usage**

If you use the standard distribution available from [download.eclipse.org/jetty/](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) you have the `start.jar` that can be used to start/stop jetty itself.

Once you have unpacked your jetty-distribution, you'll find a `start.jar` in the top most directory.  This can be used as the following.

The process that starts jetty:

```
$ java -jar start.jar STOP.PORT=28282 STOP.KEY=secret
```

The process that stops jetty:

```
$ java -jar start.jar STOP.PORT=28282 STOP.KEY=secret --stop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used stop(), but I still was able to send a request, so I thought it didn't work. But I think, my problem was, that I started more than just one instance. Now I have a start and restart method, that I can call in terminal and it works. I will have to add an authentification to my start and stop methods, but that is another problem.

Comment: Hey, do you know if there is a way of restarting jetty without resuming the the thread that joined()?

Comment: A key point to this answer is using the STOP.KEY setting.  I was first trying the process with only STOP.PORT and I could not stop Jetty from another terminal process.  Once I found this answer, I tried adding STOP.KEY and then the --stop worked from another terminal process.

Answer (score 3):

If jetty as maven plugin, you stop the server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm terminate.