# Running a web application (WAR) with embedded jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, war

I have made a very basic web application that has only one html page. I exported it as a war.

Now I created an embedded jetty server.

```
public class SimplestServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Server server = new Server(8000);

    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\jetty\\JettyWar.war");
    server.setHandler(webapp);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

}

I created a jar for this embedded server. But when I try to run my web application through the embedded server,I get the following error.

C:\Users\User>java -jar C:\Users\User\Desktop\jetty\webServer.jar

> C:\Users\User>java -jar C:\Users\User\Desktop\jetty\webServer.jar ..
>   2014-02-18 22:43:15.400:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
>   2014-02-18 22:43:15.490:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/jetty/JettyWar.war!/ to
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Loca
>   \jetty-0.0.0.0-8000-JettyWar.war-*-any-\webapp 2014-02-18
>   22:43:15.878:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED jsp:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.(JspServlet.java:68)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1075)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:957)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:514)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at com.windows.services.SimplestServer.main(SimplestServer.java:41)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.(JspServlet.java:68)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1075)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:957)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:514)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at com.windows.services.SimplestServer.main(SimplestServer.java:41)
>   2014-02-18 22:43:15.909:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8000-Je
>   .war-*-any-/webapp/},C:\Users\User\Desktop\jetty\JettyWar.war:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.(JspServlet.java:68)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1075)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:957)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:514)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at com.windows.services.SimplestServer.main(SimplestServer.java:41)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.(JspServlet.java:68)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1075)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:957)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:514)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at com.windows.services.SimplestServer.main(SimplestServer.java:41)

I have used jetty 8.1.14.
I cant understand why I am getting apache's no class def error when I selected j2ee preview in my target runtime. By the way, I got the same error when I had used apache tomcat in runtime.

Also note that I am not using maven or ant. I dont want to use either. I wish to do it through simple java only.

Thank you in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the jetty-runner. The jetty-runner jar is directly embedded in the jetty distribution (`<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>`)

and then in your main class you just have to do something like that :

```
jettyRunner = new JettyRunner("/yourContext", "path/to/your/webApp", port);
    jettyRunner.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

One tip to those who are trying to run WAR through embedded jetty server, download jettyrunner.jar.

create a bat file. and run your war directly through the jettyrunner without writing any code to make jetty server.

    java -jar jetty-runner.jar my.war

It worked for me.

Comment: Jérôme, one more help.

Can you help me to stop jettyrunner?
At the moment I am doing by killing the process by Ctrl+C in command prompt. Is there any command to kill it so that i create a bat/shell file to stop my server?

Comment: <code>$ java -jar start.jar STOP.PORT=28282 STOP.KEY=secret --stop</code> excerpt from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981435/how-do-i-stop-jetty

Comment: After successfully able to run a WAR through jetty, I am trying to embed jetty server into my web-application. It is a normal java application consisting servlet. I have used exploded WAR directory (WARless). 

But I get the following exception.