# How Deploy Spring Boot App whit Jetty and Jenkins

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, jetty

I want to deploy app to remote server using Jenkins. First I using Jenkins and download from the repository the application with the .jar file. Then I build it using maven. Next I want to run the application using "send build artifacts over ssh" and the bash command. After downloading the application again, I must have to stop the jetty server and restart it. How can I do this? What commands to use? Maybe this is a stupid question but today it was my first time when I using Jetty

Answer (score 2):

You can start Jetty with the following command:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar
```

and stop it like the following:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT=8080 -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop
```

More information can be found here:

1. [Official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/startup.html)
2. [How do I stop Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981435/how-do-i-stop-jetty)
3. https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/07/26/jetty-stop-a-jetty-server-by-command/

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I know this command:  java -DSTOP.PORT = 8080 -DSTOP.KEY = stop_jetty -jar start.jar --stop   its start me applications and does not stop. It stops until I close the terminal

Comment: or press ctrl + c